# On Trigger: System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101

Tags: apex, trigger, query, performance

I have issue with the below code when executing gives the error "`System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101`". Is there a way to optimize the below code?

As per the error log, it happens when executing "`Select Id, Country_Key__c, Description__c,.....`"

```
for (Samples__c s: Trigger.new) {    

        String countryKey = s.Country__c;
        String regionKey = s.State_Province__c;         
        countryKey = countryKey.toUpperCase();
        Map<String, String> countryCodeMap = new Map<String, String>();


        Map < String, Map < String, Validation_Region__c >> validRegions = new Map < String, Map < String, Validation_Region__c >> ();

        for (Validation_Region__c objR: [Select Id, Country_Key__c, Description__c, Name FROM Validation_Region__c WHERE Country_Key__c = :countryKey ]) {
            String countryKeyInner = objR.Country_Key__c;
            Map < String, Validation_Region__c > regionMap = validRegions.get(countryKey);

            if (regionMap == null) {
                regionMap = new Map < String, Validation_Region__c > ();
                validRegions.put(countryKeyInner, regionMap);
            }
            string regionKeys = objR.Name;
            regionMap.put(regionKeys, objR);
        }
        if ((countryKey == 'HK'  || countryKey == 'IE') && (s.Zip_Postal_Code__c.length() > 0)) { //Condition for length of  0!
            s.addError('There is an error. ' + countryKey + ' do not have postal codes.');               
        }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before your loop over `Trigger.new`, do this single query for the `Validation_Region__c` objects for all the country keys:

```
Map<String, List<Validation_Region__c>> m = new Map<String, List<Validation_Region__c>>();
for (Samples__c s: Trigger.new) {
    m.put(s.Country__c.toUpperCase(), new List<Validation_Region__c>());
}
for (Validation_Region__c r : [
        Select Id, Country_Key__c, Description__c, Name
        FROM Validation_Region__c
        WHERE Country_Key__c in :m.keySet()
        ]) {
    m.get(r.Country_Key__c.toUpperCase()).add(r);
}
```

and then inside your `Trigger.new` loop you can get the list of `Validation_Region__c` objects without any further queries from the map:

```
for (Validation_Region__c objR: m.get(countryKey)) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: Thank you Keith!! <br/> I also need to get another field "Zip_Postal_Code__c" from the Trigger.new to be used along with Country__c. How can I add that to the Map?

Comment: @Gopi Not entirely sure what logic you are looking for. But if its Validation_Region__c keyed by a zip code, have a second map created and used much like the `m` map except using Validation_Region__c as the key.